# Specify which logical database to use with spring-data-redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-session, spring-data-redis

I'm using `spring-data-redis`, `spring-session` and Spring Boot to connect to my Redis instance. However I would like `spring-data-redis` to connect not to DB 0 (which is default) but to another local database (say DB 1). This is where I'd like the sessions to be stored. Is this possible with spring-data-redis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ConnectionFactory` used by `RedisTemplate` offers configuration options for setting a default DB. Depending on the Redis driver in use both `JedisConnectionFactory` as well as `LettuceConnectionFactory` offer `void setDatabase(int index)`.

Using Spring Boot `RedisProperties` allows to set the default DB via `setDatabase` or by providing `spring.redis.database`.

Comment: Christoph Strobl is it ok if I inject JedisConnectionFactory in my bean and change database in runtime, cause I need to have two different databases??

Comment: I would not recommend doing this but rather use the `select` method offered via `RedisConnectionCommands` on the dedicated connection you're working with.

Comment: Thank you, I need to call to two different databases in one application.

Comment: Christoph Strobl how can I get 'RedisConnectionCommands' ?? I just can get connection from connectionFactory.getConnection().select(index), but it will take a new connection.

Comment: and I am using JedisConnectionFactory, is it true that the JedisConnectionFactory only supports connecting to one Redis database at a time??

Comment: Using `Jedis` the connection factory will give you a connection from the pool. When using the `ConnectionFactory` along with the template switching `db` on factory level might result in strange behavior especially in multithreaded environments, assuming the factory is registered as a spring bean in context. Therefore it's safer to select the `db` after retrieving the connection from the factory. One way would be to set up multiple dedicated factories and templates - one for each db.

Comment: Agree, I've decided to do in on connection level, I use redisTemplate.execute( con -> {con.select(dbIndex); // do stuff }